# Trying to compare to values in a pandas dataframe for max value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

I've got a pandas dataframe, and I'm trying to fill a new column in the dataframe, which takes the maximum value of two values situated in another column of the dataframe, iteratively. I'm trying to build a loop to do this, and save time with computation as I realise I could probably do it with more lines of code.

```
for x in ((jac_input.index)):
    jac_output['Max Load'][x] = jac_input[['load'][x],['load'][x+1]].max()
```

However, I keep getting this error during the comparison

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any ideas as to where I'm going wrong here? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many things are wrong with your current code.

When you do `['abc'][x]`, `x` can only take the value `0` and this will return `'abc'` as you are slicing **a list**. Not at all what you expect it to do (I imagine, slicing the Series).

For your code to be valid, you should do something like:

```
jac_input = pd.DataFrame({'load': [1,0,3,2,5,4]})
for x in jac_input.index:
    print(jac_input['load'].loc[x:x+1].max())
```

output:

```
1
3
3
5
5
4
```

Also, when assigning, if you use `jac_output['Max Load'][x] = ...` you will likely encounter a [`SettingWithCopyWarning`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas). You should rather use `loc`: `jac_outputLoc[x, 'Max Load'] =` .

**But you do not need all that, use vectorial code instead!**

You can perform [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) on the reversed dataframe:

```
jac_output['Max Load'] = jac_input['load'][::-1].rolling(2, min_periods=1).max()[::-1]
```

Or using [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
jac_output['Max Load'] = pd.concat([jac_input['load'], jac_input['load'].shift(-1)], axis=1).max(1)
```

output (without assignment):

```
0    1.0
1    3.0
2    3.0
3    5.0
4    5.0
5    4.0
dtype: float64
```